# ConcurrentModificationException when using createDrawingPatriarch() in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, concurrentmodification

Here is the thing.

I have been using Apache POI to manipulate Excel files for my app. When I need to add a comment on a cell, POI provides sheet.createDrawingPatriarch() to obtain the basic object to further usage.

But when I executed my app, JVM threw an exception.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.findDrawingGroup(InternalWorkbook.java:2229)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.getPatriarch(HSSFSheet.java:2044)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.createDrawingPatriarch(HSSFSheet.java:2036)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.createDrawingPatriarch(HSSFSheet.java:83)
    at utility.BasicUtility.smellyCellMark(BasicUtility.java:608)
    at programEntry.TestWorksheet.testWorksheet(TestWorksheet.java:246)
    at programEntry.TestWorksheet.run(TestWorksheet.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I searched corresponding root causes resulting in this exception. But in my app, I just invoked two methods provided by POI.

```
CreationHelper factory = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
Drawing drawing        = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();  // 1, exception reported from here.
ClientAnchor anchor    = factory.createClientAnchor();
Comment comment        = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);  // 2
```

I think that it may be a potential bug in Apache POI library but I didn't know how to avoid or fix this exception in my app. Any advice? If needed, I can provide more debugging information.

Any advice?

Comment: [Can I access/modify workbooks/documents/slideshows in multiple threads?](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10224): In short: Handling different document-objects in different threads will work. Accessing the same document in multiple threads will not work.

Comment: @AxelRichter I think you are right. However, I used multi-threading for speed. So a better way for me is to use some lock or synchronization when multi-threads concurrently manipulate the same Excel file. Anyway, thanks a lot for your comment.